# Numerical output of "sortable" divs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a page with four divs arranged one under the other, they are sortable using jQuery (using the touch sortable from here: 
http://touchpunch.furf.com)
I want that evey order will have an output of a number:

order of 1,2,3,4 will have id 1
Order of 1,3,2,4 will have id 2
Etc. (24 Id numbers total)

I want put the result in a hidden input inside a form and save to MySQL database. like here:

...

"document.write('');"

...

Any idea how to make it?

Edit: might use array as well, but still no idea how to make it work.

Comment: Saving order this way is bad idea, it's unreadable. Maybe save it as an array in JSON format?

Comment: what code have you tried so far, and does saving to MySQL with a javascript command work ???

Comment: billy - only the sortable, no change (no idea where to begin from, thats why i ask), and saving does work for me :) . Robo - haven't got much into JSON yet, and would like to learn it but don't have much time right now.